# Faster/better way to extract string with a substring present in a list?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

I have a couple of lists `generator = ["one#zade", "one#zaat", "one#osde", "one#za"]` & `accepted_channels = ["zade", "zaat"]`.

I am trying to extract elements from the `generator` list which have as a substring any one of the values that are present in the `accepted_channels` list.

I have a code and it works correctly, but it has 3 loops involved. Is there a way to write the code without any loops or with a reduced number of loops?

```
generator = ["one#zade", "one#zaat", "one#osde", "one#za"]
accepted_channels = ["zade", "zaat"]
final_records = []
for item in generator:
    for channel in accepted_channels:
        if channel in item:
            final_records.append(item)
            
print(final_records) # prints ['one#zade', 'one#zaat']
```

P.S.: Here, the `generator` only has 4 elements, but in real I have a list of more than 50000 elements.

Comment: Are you looking strictly for **any** substring or the part after the hash character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use *filter()*

```
generator = ["one#zade", "one#zaat", "one#osde", "one#za"]
accepted_channels = ["zade", "zaat"]

def check(s):
    return any(y in s for y in accepted_channels)

print(list(filter(check, generator)))
```

**Output:**

```
['one#zade', 'one#zaat']
```

**Performance check:**

Built *generator* list with 50_000 elements each of 8 pseudo-random characters. Duration was 0.016s

Comment: i was curious and did some performance testing (might be wrong) but it turns out that the original function is the fastest for some reason. both your and the original solution have O(n*m) where n is len of the generator and m is the len of accepted_channels. here's the testing script https://pastebin.com/1EdJpA9B